# How do I restrict a user to update and for anyone to search?

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I would like to lock down my AWS Elasticsearch instance so that only users I specify are allowed to "update" the index (usually with a `/_bulk` request but also deleting and creating indexes) and anyone can "search" the index (with a `/_search` request).

This is what I thought would work:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::$myRootID:user/$myUserName"
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttpPost",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:$myRootID:domain/myDomainName/*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "AllowAnonymousHTTPGET",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "*"
      },
      "Action": "es:ESHttpPost",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:es:us-west-2:$myRootID:domain/$myDomainName/_search"
    }
  ]
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I also need both to `POST` as I can't send a body with a `GET` request in my case.

The error I get:

```
User: arn:aws:iam::$myRootID:user/$myUserName is not authorized to perform: es:ESHttpPost on resource: $myDomainName
```